# How to integrate the excel range into one single table?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have two ranges in the excel file .
(A79-I84) & (A90-I92)

I am now using the `Excel.RANGE.copy.` to copy the two tables and paste on the word file .

However , the two ranges become two separate tables and the original excel table format cannot inherit to the new word file .Also , some cells from the word report will be shown in two lines .

In conclusion , the format of the word report will be very messy .
How to integrate the two table into one table with good table format or alignments?

the new table will be generated like this :
(red pen = problems )

[image]

My codes:

```
 Sub ExcelRangeToWord()


Dim tbl0 As Excel.RANGE
Dim tbl As Excel.RANGE
Dim tbl2 As Excel.RANGE

Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim myDoc As Word.Document
Dim WordTable As Word.Table

'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False

'Copy Range from Excel
  'Set tbl0 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet9.Name).RANGE("A78:I83")
  Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet9.Name).RANGE("A78:I83")
  Set tbl2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet9.Name).RANGE("A90:I92")

'Create an Instance of MS Word
  On Error Resume Next

    'Is MS Word already opened?
      Set WordApp = GetObject(Class:="Word.Application")

    'Clear the error between errors
      Err.Clear

    'If MS Word is not already open then open MS Word
      If WordApp Is Nothing Then Set WordApp = CreateObject(Class:="Word.Application")

    'Handle if the Word Application is not found
      If Err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox "Microsoft Word could not be found, aborting."
        GoTo EndRoutine
      End If

  On Error GoTo 0

'Make MS Word Visible and Active
  WordApp.Visible = True
  WordApp.Activate

'Create a New Document
  Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add



'Trigger copy separately for each table + paste for each table

    tbl.Copy ' paste range1
    myDoc.Paragraphs(1).RANGE.PasteExcelTable _
        LinkedToExcel:=False, _
        WordFormatting:=True, _
        RTF:=False

'before that...
'...go to end of doc and add new paragraph
    myDoc.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").RANGE.InsertParagraphAfter
    tbl2.Copy 'paste range2

'Paste Table into MS Word last paragraph
    myDoc.Paragraphs(myDoc.Paragraphs.Count).RANGE.PasteExcelTable _
        LinkedToExcel:=False, _
        WordFormatting:=True, _
        RTF:=False



'Autofit Table so it fits inside Word Document
  Set WordTable = myDoc.Tables(1)
  WordTable.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)

EndRoutine:
'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True

'Clear The Clipboard
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

## new aftereffect

[image]

Comment: Is there  no way to hide rows in between, set print-area around the now adjacent ranges and export that as an image or object in some way?

Comment: Is that possible to export the two ranges into a big table and an image using vba ?

Comment: Do you need to be able to edit the object once it is in Word?

Comment: @QHarr No need . This is the report for later printing or mail

Comment: Try the answer i have posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. Simply hide rows in between (which ever you don't want to see) and copy as one range to be from "A79:I92" and paste as a picture. Credit [here](https://blog.qiqitori.com/?p=115) ([@sneep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3592381/sneep)) for sub to resize image. Note this will resize all images but could be adapted to target just one.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExcelRangeToWord()


    Dim tbl0 As Excel.Range
    Dim Tbl As Excel.Range
    Dim tbl2 As Excel.Range

    Dim wordApp As Word.Application
    Dim myDoc As Word.Document
    Dim WordTable As Word.Table
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")             ' Change e.g. sheet9.Name
    'Optimize Code
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    ws.Rows("84:89").EntireRow.Hidden = True 'ADJUST AS APPROPRIATE

    'Copy Range from Excel
    'Set tbl0 = ws.RANGE("A78:I83")
    Set Tbl = ws.Range("A78:I92")


    ' Set tbl2 = ws.Range("A90:I92")

    'Create an Instance of MS Word
    On Error Resume Next

    'Is MS Word already opened?
    Set wordApp = GetObject(Class:="Word.Application")

    'Clear the error between errors
    Err.Clear

    'If MS Word is not already open then open MS Word
    If wordApp Is Nothing Then Set wordApp = CreateObject(Class:="Word.Application")

    'Handle if the Word Application is not found
    If Err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox "Microsoft Word could not be found, aborting."
        GoTo EndRoutine
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

    'Make MS Word Visible and Active
    wordApp.Visible = True
    wordApp.Activate

    'Create a New Document
    Set myDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add

    'Trigger copy separately for each table + paste for each table

    Tbl.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

    wordApp.Selection.Paste
    wordApp.Selection.TypeParagraph

    wordApp.Selection.PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientLandscape

    resize_all_images_to_page_width myDoc

EndRoutine:
    'Optimize Code
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    'Clear The Clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub


Sub resize_all_images_to_page_width(myDoc As Document)
  'https://blog.qiqitori.com/?p=115
    Dim inline_shape As InlineShape
    Dim percent As Double

    For Each inline_shape In myDoc.InlineShapes
        inline_shape.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        inline_shape.ScaleWidth = 100
        inline_shape.ScaleHeight = 100
        percent = myDoc.PageSetup.TextColumns.Width / inline_shape.Width
        inline_shape.ScaleWidth = percent * 100
        inline_shape.ScaleHeight = percent * 100
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: It still cannot inherit the alignment(center alignment ) from the original excel .Also ,some cell in the original excel have been divided into 2 lines  in the new word report .How to improve the new table format  ?

Comment: You have applied the following  WordTable.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow) so the original alignment will change.

Comment: Can you add an image of how it looks in Excel?

Comment: Added . Btw , I found that your code cannot successfully join the second table (excel range 2)

Comment: bro one more question .Is it more difficult to paste as table format ?As  for some reason ,  it is more flexible for the future table modification . If not , it is possible for the object(picture ) to best fit the word document ?(so that ,I don't have to modify the picture size for everytimes .) Lastly , is it possible to pre-set the page to landscape orientation in Word before pasting the picture ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159661/discussion-between-qharr-and-vito).